# Error in reading .dat file in python

Tags: python, file-io, numpy

I tried to read a .dat file in python using the snippet below:

```
old = numpy.loadtxt('C:\Users\Downloads\new.dat',delimiter=',')
```

This gives the following error:

```
[Errno 22] invalid mode ('U') or filename:'C:\\Users\\Downloads\new.dat'
```

However, it worked for many other .dat files. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: I think the file does not exist.

Comment: Make your filepath/name string either raw by prefixing it with an r like `r'C:\blah` or escape your backslashes as `\n` is a newline character.

Answer (score 0):

Read this and as mentioned before, raw the string.
https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/gotcha-%E2%80%94-backslashes-in-windows-filenames/